# Laravel Eloquent get where doesnt have, search where has when not null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This question is really hard to word, so I apologise for the title!

Lets say I have a `Rooms` model and a `Bookings` model, 1 room can have many bookings.

I am building a table with filters, and I need to be able to run a filter on the booking relationship IF there is a booking, else grab the record anyway.

Lets say my room has a booking relationship like so

```
public function latestBooking(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Bookings', 'room_id', 'id')
    ->orderBy('expiry_date', 'DESC')->limit(1);
}
```

The above relationship gets me the latest booking.

I'm running a 'vacant from' filter like so

```
if ($request->has('filters.vacant_from')) {
    $rooms = $rooms->whereHas('latestBooking', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('expiry_date', '<', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request->input('filters.vacant_from'))->format('Y-m-d'));
    });
}
```

The issue is that this only gets rooms that have a booking and are available after the date specified. I need it to be able to search all rooms, if it does have a booking, check if the expiry date is after the date specified, if it doesn't have a latest booking, get it anyway as its a vacant room.

Basically how would I structure my filter function so that it runs like this

**Search all rooms, if it has a latest booking, check its expiry date is after the date specified and only grab it if its true/vacant, if it doesn't have a latest booking then grab it anyway as it is vacant**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a suggestion for you regarding your `latestBookingRelationship`. You should create another relationship and add a `greater than today` condition to it and maybe name it `activeLatestBooking`.

Then, your latest Booking should comprise all booking rooms irrespective of whether their booking is active or not.

```
public function activeLatestBooking(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Bookings', 'room_id', 'id')
        ->where('expiry_date', '>', date('d/m/Y', strtotime('today')))->orderBy('expiry_date', 'DESC')->limit(1);
    }

public function latestBooking(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Bookings', 'room_id', 'id')
    ->orderBy('expiry_date', 'DESC')->limit(1);
}
```

Then, to answer your question:

```
if ($request->has('filters.vacant_from')) {
        $rooms = $rooms->whereHas('latestBooking', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('expiry_date', '<', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request->input('filters.vacant_from'))->format('Y-m-d'));
        })->orWhereDoesntHave('latestBooking');
    }
```

What the filter query does is this: It gets all latest bookings whose `expiry_date` is less than the `vacant_from` date...and the `orWhereDoesntHave` gets all rooms that have never been booked.

Comment: Adding the 'orWhereDoesntHave', i think is the cleanest way to achieve my goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the booking relationship should be like this,

```
public function latestBooking(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Bookings')->orderBy('expiry_date', 'DESC');
}
```

as this is a one to many relationship. [laravel relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

and you can write your filter like this,

```
  if ($request->has('filters.vacant_from')) {
        $rooms = $rooms->whereHas('latestBooking', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereDate('expiry_date', '<', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request->input('filters.vacant_from'))->format('Y-m-d'));
        });
    }
```

you can use `whereDate` to run date queries in laravel. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `hasMany` relation between `Rooms` and `Bookings` model with name `bookings`

```
$rooms = Rooms::whereHas('bookings', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereDate('expiry_date', '<', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request->input('filters.vacant_from'))->format('Y-m-d'));
        })->orWhereDoesntHave('bookings')->get();
```

Comment: But isn't this only going to return rows that do not have a booking?

Comment: But then this is only searching the rows that do not have a latest booking? I need it to be 'if it does have a booking, search, if it doesn't have a booking, grab it aswell'

Comment: it will search either doesn't have booking or have booking but expire date is before  the searched date. no need to check latest booking. just to check if room is booked then does its expire date is before search date then return